# JSON posted in body of http.request comes up null on ASP.NET server side

Tags: c#, json, node.js, http, asp.net-web-api

I am having an issue with posting JSON to my web server I have a ASP.NET web application running on a server that utilizes attribute routing to route requests. Here's the problem area of that project:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("users/new")]
public string PostDataModel([FromBody] dataModel jsonObj)
{
   try
     {
         WebApiApplication.db.AddToDatabase(jsonObj);
         return "successfully inserted into database";
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Tools.Logger.log("[POST DATA][ERROR] : " + ex.Message);
         return ex.Message;
     }
}
```

As of now, using Postman to manually send a POST request with the JSON inserted into the request body, and the Content-Type set to application/json, the function successfully parses the JSON into the correct object specified ([FromBody] DataModel). Also I do have accessors for all the properties in DataModel.

The issue comes in with my unit tests. I created a Node.js project to do some unit testing against the API. I am using the http module to do this. Heres where the requests are made:

```
req = http.request(options, (response) => {
     var body = '';

     response.on('data', (d) => {
        body += d;
     });
     response.on('end', () => {
        if (options.method == 'POST') {
           options.body = JSON.stringify(options.body);
     });
)};
```

the "options" parameter is defined as:

```
 var options = {
     method: 'POST',
     host: customSite,
     path: '/users/new',
     headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' },         
     body: {
            'UserId': "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            'UserName': "Testing Suite",
            'Name': "Tester",
            'Email': "tester@test.com",
            'Password': "fake,",
            'BirthDate': "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM",
            'NumberOfItems': 0,
            'Links': [],
            'TotalLikes': 100
     },        
 }
```

Now when I run the unit test the API throws an exception which is caught which comes out as : **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."**

The JSON I'm passing in the unit test is literally copied and pasted from the POST request i used in Postman, which worked. I cannot figure out what the issue is that is causing the API to fail when hit from my Node.js unit tests and to succeed when hit from Postman.

Comment: Can you code a simple Unit Test in C# to see what happens? :-)

Comment: Ill try that tonight, our client side application is written in Swift 3 and we use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) to do all HTTP requests. Apparently Alamofire has no problem getting the JSON passed to the API to be parsed out correctly